# BackgrounDRB + Ruby script

Tags: ruby, backgroundrb

I "would like" to schedule a ruby script with BackgrounDRb. Is it possible?
I read the examples from these two websites, but I didn't find an answer:

- [BackgrounDRb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/)
- [Using BackgrounDRb asynchronously](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/161-using-backgroundrb-to-execute-tasks-asynchronously-in-rails)

Thank you.

Comment: That BackgrounDRb gem hasn't been touched for 5 years. Switch to resque or sidekiq if you can for background jobs.

Comment: I agree, but I had to use that at my work. Anyway, I found the solution, I had to create a worker and copy past my script in it. So now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is impossible to execute a ruby script from a backgroundrb worker, or at least I wasn't able to do it. 
The best way that I found was to rewrite (mostly copy/paste) my ruby script into a specific worker and it works fine.